# Kernel headers for VMware tools

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, vmware, header-file

I tried to compile VMware tools on my server. I compiled the kernel myself, I didn't use RPM. As VMware tools needs the kernel header files, I executed the following command in my kernel folder source:

```
make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/tmp/header/
```

All files are exported to `/tmp/header/include/`. When I start the `vmware-config-tools.pl` and I specify the folder `/tmp/header/`, VMware tools says:

> The path "/tmp/header/include/" is not a valid path to the 3.3.0 kernel

What is wrong here?

---

**Edit**: I'm running RHEL 6, kernel 3.3, trying to compile VMware tools for ESXi 4.1 & 5

Comment: /tmp is frequently cleaned out (even each boot).

Comment: Yes I know, but that is just for the test.

Answer (score 0):

vmware-tools need the full kernel headers.

probably that make headers_install is not exporting everything that vmware needs. try copying the real kernel source and test. if it works, remove all files except the .h

```
find /tmp/headers-full -not -name \*.h -delete
```

and test again. if it works, compare both header trees to see what is missing

Comment: Hello, as you advise me I took all the kernel source and the installer is still complaining. I think vmware is expecting some special path for the kernel headers such as /lib/modules/ /usr/src/ etc... As I am not able to decode all the function in the perl script I will never found the solution...!